# ReactJs ErrorBoundary not working in simplest scenario

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to get my `ErrorBoundary` to work.

The `ErrorBoundary` is as simple as in the most examples:

```
export class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component<IErrorBoundaryProps, IErrorBoundaryState> {
    componentDidCatch(error: Error, errorInfo: Object): void {
        this.setState({ catchedError: error });
    }

    render(): JSX.Element | React.ReactNode {
        const { children } = this.props;
        const { catchedError } = this.state;

        if (catchedError)
            return (<div>Something went wrong</div>);

        // return the children
        return children;
    }
}
```

And another component using the ErrorBoundary:

```
export class Test extends React.Component<ITestProps, ITestState> {
    render(): JSX.Element | React.ReactNode {
        const test:string = null;

        return (
            <ErrorBoundary>
                {test.length}
            </ErrorBoundary>
        );
    }
}
```

However, the `Something went wrong` is never shown. I have no idea what is going wrong here as all the examples out there do the same.
Any ideas where to start from finding the issue?

Comment: You are actually throwing the error within the render of the Error boundary, not within the lifecycle of its children, thus error is not catched properly.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to define your state

```
constructor(...args){
  super(...args);
  this.state = {
    catchedError: false
  }
}
```

Then throw an error inside `Test` component

```
function Test(){
  throw new Error('I crashed!');
}
```

And when you render both these components like below

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <ErrorBoundary>
    <Test/>          
  </ErrorBoundary>
  ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

You will get expected result. [`Worked demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/182709/)

The idea of `Error Boundaries` is to wrap the component which throws an error.

From [`react docs`](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html)

> Note that error boundaries only catch errors in the components below
>   them in the tree. An error boundary can’t catch an error within
>   itself. If an error boundary fails trying to render the error message,
>   the error will propagate to the closest error boundary above it. This,
>   too, is similar to how catch {} block works in JavaScript.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Indeed your example is working. Thanks. 
So there is no way I can wrap my component itself in `<ErrorBoundary>`? I have to create a new component just to wrap this one in the boundary?

Comment: @KingKerosin yes or implement `componentDidCatch` method and handle it within this method

Comment: The interesting part (at least for me): The idea of Error Boundaries is to wrap the component which throws an error.

Because it MUST be a component, not a just a regular child node.